# Can't get the correct division result by `/` and `np.divide`

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, division

I want to get the average of x.

```
current_x = sh600004['daily return'][i] #I printed the value of current_x, this line of code works fine.
x_list.append(current_x)
x_sum = sum(x_list)
x_average = x_sum/len(x_list))
```

I printed out the value for `x_sum` is -0.00376506024096, `len(x_list)` is 60. `x_average` is -0.00376506024096.

But the `x_average` should be`-0.00376506024096/60 = -6.2751004016e-05`. I tried `np.divide()`, `/` and`float(x_sum)/float(len(x_list))`. None of them worked.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Are you sure `len(x_list)` is 60? Did you actually `print(len(x_list))` to check that?

Comment: I did. I print all the variables I mentioned above to check. I don't understand why this happening

Comment: It's not possible to verify the problem. Please create a minimal complete example to reproduce that result.